# Gatsby: Generate nested dynamic routes

Tags: gatsby

I'm trying to generate some client-only routes, for the following URLs:

`/products/anything/this-page`

Gatsby generates URLs like `/products/anything/`.

I've tried:

```js
exports.onCreatePage = async ({ page, actions }) => {
    const { createPage } = actions

    if (page.path.match(/^\/product/)) {
        page.matchPath = '/product/*'
        createPage(page)
    }
}
```

to no avail...

Also, a more complex regex

```js
   if (page.path.match(/^product\/.*\/.*/)) {
        page.matchPath = /^product\/.*\/.*/
        createPage(page)
    }
```

Comment: Were you able to find a solve?

Comment: I'm afraid not...

Comment: Your example code work when I tried it in this CodeSandbox (https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-burnell-kbb6k?file=/gatsby-node.js). `/anything/this-page` lands on the product page. Is this not what you are seeing? Or is there another missing piece I am not understanding?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to create nested route after your dynamic slug. In your gatsby-node.js file:

```
  exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions

  const { data } = await graphql(`
    query {
      //your query here
    }
  `)

  data.allProducts.edges.forEach(edge => {
    const slug = edge.node.productId
     
    //create your dynamic page

    createPage({
      path: `/products/${slug}/`,
      component: require.resolve(
        "./src/components/products/templates/product-template/ProductTemplate.tsx"
      ),
      context: { productData: edge.node },
    })

    //create nested route in it

    createPage({
      path: `/products/${slug}/something/`,
      component: require.resolve(
        "./src/components/trainings/templates/something/something.tsx"
      ),
      context: { productData: edge.node },
    })
  })
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In the onCreatePage function you can create the url to the page dynamically:

```
// The all allWcProduct is a custom node I've added, but could be replaced with 
another node you have on your site instead.
const path = require("path")
const pageQuery = `
    {
      allWcProduct{
        edges{
          node{
            slug
            name
          }
        }
      }
    }
    `

exports.createPages = ({ graphql, actions }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    graphql(pageQuery).then(results => {

      if (results.errors) {
        console.log(results.errors)
        reject(results.errors)
      }
      results.data.allWcProduct.edges.forEach(({ node }) => {
        createPage({
          path: `/products/${node.slug}`,
          component: path.resolve(`./src/components/products/productDetailPage.tsx`),
          context: {
            slug: node.slug // send this to the component itself as a prop
          }
        })
      })
    })
    resolve()
  })

}
```

As was said above, you could use the plugin as well for more basic usages.

Comment: Hello, I am trying to create dynamic client only routes.  Not statically rendered pages.

Comment: I see, then you want something like Next.js, Gatsby is a static site generator essentially. The above code only generates dynamic static pages based on data you provide it via GraphQL.

Comment: @SpencerBigum: that's a [misconception](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/adding-app-and-website-functionality/).

Comment: @magicspon Yeah i want to do something similar but didn't find any workaround. If you are able to do it then please let me know